# TSQL Bitwise Operations: How do I find out common groupings of values?

Tags: t-sql, statistics, bitwise-operators

Background:  I am looking at consolidating security roles for an application.  There are 20 roles that can apply to one or more of five access levels (like district, county, state).  Most users have multiple roles for each access level, so I wanted to get statistics on what the most common groupings are for users by access level.

**EDIT:** The business users were confused between job roles of the people who are entered into the system and security roles for people who use the system.  There was a direct mapping between the job roles and the security roles.  What the business owners are finding is that they don't want to manage the security for the number of roles that a user can possibly be assigned.

I created the equivalent of a flags enum for the roles (Id is the primary key of the Role, and the flag is my flay value):

```
DECLARE @flags table(Id int,Flag int);
insert into @flags
values (1 , 1),
(2 , 2), 
(4 , 4),  
(5 , 8),  
(6 , 16), 
(7 , 32), 
(8 , 64), 
(9 , 128), 
(10 , 256), 
(11 , 512), 
(12 , 1024), 
(13 , 2048), 
(14 , 4096), 
(15 , 8192), 
(16 , 16384), 
(17 , 32768), 
(18 , 65536), 
(19 , 131072),
(20 , 262144),
(21 , 524288)
```

I've queried out the SUM of user roles for each of the users in the system grouped by access level and would like to query out what the most common role groupings are for the user population so that I can ensure that I don't make the new role set too general.

```
UserName        Roles   AccessLevel
User1@test.edu  8192    County
User1@test.edu  262400  District
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be good.  I'm not very versed in statistics, so if the whole method I'm using is bad, let me know.

Comment: An imperative way to do this would be to loop through each record and check the remainder to determine if a user is in each role.

Comment: What I don't get is that you need to base roles on statistics?  SQL will handle millions of roles.   Build the roles and districts for what makes business sense.   If the user wants 400 roles and they are willing to mange those roles then so what?  If at an app level roles are costing support and development time the make it a feature and tell them the cost and let the user prioritize it versus other features.  I so disagree that statistics is the answer here - not like you want to identify a trend.

Comment: @Blam - The problem is that the administrators do not want to manage page or control level permissions for the number of roles that they originally came up with.  The business owners don't have a good grasp on what their users are doing in the field, and I don't have the ability to talk to the users directly.

Comment: 20 roles seems like a pretty small set.  That's subjective, and depends on the size of the enterprise and granularity of permissions.  What are the minimum and maximum number of roles you'd want to use to model a user profile?  How many profiles are you trying to get down to?